# Change UV Positions for Linked Objects?

Tags: mesh, uv, linked-data

How would I go about editing the UV layout of a linked object without changing the UV positions of the other linked objects? I'm trying to share the mesh geometry between dozens of objects while using different UVs on a shared TextureAtlas. Is this even possible? I've spent days trying to figure this out, but I haven't found an answer yet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What render engine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use the *[UV Warp modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Modify/UV_Warp)*:

   > UV Warp uses 2 objects to define a transformation which is applied to the UV coordinates.
2. Alternatively it can be done in the material using the [*Mapping* node](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes/More#Mapping) (for BI [see here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Materials/Nodes/Types/Vector#Mapping_Node) or [texture *Mapping* panel](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures/Mapping#http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures/Mapping) for non node materials). Obviously [linking the material to the Object(s)](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Materials/Assigning_a_material#New_Material_Panel_Buttons) will be required.

Answer (score 4):

#### Use Different UV Maps

It is possible. The list of UV maps is attached to `Mesh` data, each objects sharing that same data can't have a different set of UV maps. But each object's material *can* be attached to itself instead of its data, and its texture can use any available UV map.

First, create all UV maps to be used in the same object data (max. 8).

[image: 1]

Then create different materials for each objects, set the material's `link` property to `Object`.

[image: 2]

Then create a new image texture for each materials, referring to the same texture file but using different UV map. Its limitation is the amount of UV maps can be created for a single object data, 8 at maximum.

#### Use Different Textures

Otherwise, why not create different texture files using the same UV map? I mean, I imagine you wouldn't vary seam placement, just shifting the whole UV coordinates around. Wouldn't that be too much work and inflexible (e.g. modifying *every single map* when the mesh object is edited)?

Using one UV map as a template is easier, IMHO. And you're free to create as many texture variations as you need.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I think you gave me the info I need concerning Mesh/UV data attachments.
"why not create different texture files using the same UV map?" My models are for a mobile game so a Texture Atlas is necessary. I might be able to do some modifications before importing everything into the engine to combine all of the textures instead of doing it within blender.